# Privileges page missing site title.

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

On https://askubuntu.com/privileges there are several instances of the site title missing:

> When your fellow users vote up your questions and answers on Ubuntu, you generate reputation.

Should be "questions and answers on Ask Ubuntu"

> will be granted additional privileges on Ubuntu.

Should be on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a problem, but I will point out it seems the privileges templates are still being ironed out in most ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed. I checked https://askubuntu.com/privileges and every of the 24 subpages to make sure.